# Python: subprocess.Popen never returns

Tags: python, subprocess, threadpool

I have written a Python script which runs some svn commands using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). For example:

```
svn ls svn+ssh://url1/trunk
svn cp svn+ssh://url1/trunk svn+ssh://url1/branch/1 --parents -m "blah"
```

For each command, I create an subprocess.Popen object:

```
p = subprocesp.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

And wait for it to finish:

```
output      = p.communicate()[0].strip()
return_code = p.returncode
```

The problem is that for some `svn cp` commands that fail immediately on the shell for copying inexistent repos, **`p.communicate()` never returns**.

Extra information:

- The code is executed using a thread pool (`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`)
- The phenomena is menifested only for failing
- Using a shell, the exact same command finishes with error code 1 in less than two seconds.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, the problem was Eclipse. The script works perfectly well from the shell, but waits forever in the internal Eclipse terminal.

Comment: Your post prompted me to test the same thing with Visual Studio.. works in REPL but not from VS2015.